# Camel: redirect to url received by parameter

Tags: java, spring, cxf, apache-camel

I'm developing a poxy using Camel. Client call me with a URL like:

http://www.myserver.com/getFile?path=http://www.otherdomain.com/file.txt

I have written a Camel route:

```
<route id="getFileService">
     ...
     <from uri="bean:getFileProxy" />
     <to uri="..." />
</ route>
```

How can I get the parameter "path" and use it in the route tag `<to uri="http://www.otherdomain.com/file.txt" />` dynamically.

Then I have to send the HTTP Response to Client.

Comment: see Recipient List: http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what you are doing in your "getFileProxy" bean but you could create a simple proxy with camel components:

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:8182/proxy")
   .recipientList(simple("${header.path}?bridgeEndpoint=true"));
```

This will take all requests from `http://localhost:8182/proxy` and forwards it to the the address specified in the path property. You will need to use the [recipientList](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html) component since this is the only component that resolves its endpoint dynamically at runtime.

If you need to use the getFileProxy bean you may set a the path as a header on the exchange there and then use it in the recipientlist.

Note that this implementation depends on the path property to be a valid camel component uri and it will use the old http component and not the preferred http4 component if a regular url is specified in the path property.

Regards